# Time complexity of Collections.rotate in Java

Tags: java, performance, collections

I haven't found much information about the time complexity of Collections.rotate(list, k), am I correct in assuming the following?

- For ArrayList: O(n) being n the size of the list
- For LinkedList and ArrayDeque: O(k)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't pass an ArrayDeque to Collections.rotate, can you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the [documentation of `Collections.rotate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,int)) describes the algorithm nicely:

> If the specified list is small or implements the `RandomAccess` interface, this implementation exchanges the first element into the location it should go, and then repeatedly exchanges the displaced element into the location it should go until a displaced element is swapped into the first element. If necessary, the process is repeated on the second and successive elements, until the rotation is complete.

According to this part of the description the time complexity is O(N) for lists that implement the `RandomAccess` interface (because for such lists the element access is O(1) and the algorithm needs to access N elements), O(N^2) for lists where the element access is O(N) (for example `LinkedList`) - but only for small N.

> If the specified list is large and doesn't implement the `RandomAccess` interface, this implementation breaks the list into two sublist views around index `-distance mod size`. Then the [`reverse(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) method is invoked on each sublist view, and finally it is invoked on the entire list.

This part of the description is for larger lists that do not implement the `RandomAccess` interface (for example `LinkedList`). The description mentions 3 calls to [`Collections.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) and the [documentation for `Collections.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) says:

> This method runs in linear time.

That means O(N) for each call to `Collections.reverse()` - but O(3*N) is a constant factor to O(N) which means that the whole operation for `Collections.rotate()` also runs in O(N).

---

Note that [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) does **not** implement the `List` interface and you therefore cannot call `Collections.rotate()` with an `ArrayDeque` as argument.